# Python relative path 2 folders up

Tags: django, python-3.x

I got the following folder structure

`ProjectX/Data` and `ProjectX/mysite/core`

Inside `ProjectX/mysite/core` is my python script and that i use to create a file inside `ProjectX/Data`.

at the moment im using:

```
fileList = glob.glob(f"/var/home/USER/Documents/ProjectX/DATA/{user_name_directory}/*.pdf")
```

and

```
f = open(f'/var/home/USER/Documents/ProjectX/DATA/{user_name_directory}/data_text.txt','w')
```

if i use

```
f = open(f'~/ProjectX/DATA/{user_name_directory}/data_text.txt','w')
```

it wont work. I also want to run this django project on a windows machine.

How can i write relative path from the main ProjectX folder when the script is two folders in?

How do i get 2 folders up and then inside DATA?

EDIT:

I tried:

```
import os
def file_path(relative_path):
    dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    split_path = relative_path.split("/")
    new_path = os.path.join(dir, *split_path)
    return new_path
```

and

```
fileList = glob.glob(file_path(f"/ProjectX/DATA/{user_name_directory}/*.pdf"))
```

and below at the second part of the script also:

```
f = open(file_path(f"/ProjectX/DATA/{user_name_directory}/data_text.txt",'w'))
```

and it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os 
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print(BASE_DIR)
myurl = BASE_DIR + "/ProjectX/DATA/{user_name_directory}/data_text.txt"
with open(myurll, "w") as f:       
     blabla
```

Comment: fileList = glob.glob(BASE_DIR(f"/DATA/{user_name_directory}/*.pdf"))? Im getting an error:      BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(ProjectX)))
NameError: name 'ProjectX' is not defined

Comment: myurl = BASE_DIR + "/ProjectX/DATA/{user_name_directory}/data_text.txt"

with open(myurll, "w") as f:       blabla

Comment: instead of (file) use (__file__) I dont know why the editor change it

you can copy the command from django settings

Comment: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file)))
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Comment: Please use double underscores before and after "file", it's the editor that change the format. If you are using Django you can find the command in the settings file

Comment: Oh sorry, i ment it in a thx buddy kinda way. Also referring man to my gf